# Getting error while installing ROracle with Oracle Instant Client

Tags: r, oracle, roracle

Getting error while installing ROracle with Oracle Instant Client

```
ERROR: cannot find C:\oreclient_install_dir\instantclient-basic-windows.x64-12.1.0.2.0\instantclient_12_1/sdk/include or Oracle Client include.
       Please set OCI_INC to specify its location.
ERROR: configuration failed for package 'ROracle'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ROracle’ had non-zero exit status
```

I want to use dbConnect to oracle database.

in the above path where instant client files are there, there is no sdk in my folders.everything matches / found till there. where can I get sdk and put in here.
what to set in OCI_INC?

Answer (score 0):

The SDK comes from "Development and Runtime - **optional** packages".

That is a separate download, which you then unzip/expand into the basic instant client directory.

Comment: Thank you, User101. How and where do I get this other Development and Runtime package? Please advise.